How to use struct in .exs file
This is the content of my "test.exs" file.
defmodule Person do
    defstruct name: "", age: 0, stage: :baby
end

bob = %Person{name: "Bob"}

When I run it, I'm told:
error: cannot access struct Person, the struct was not yet defined or the struct is being accessed in the same context that defines it

So, How to use struct in .exs file where the struct is defined?

How do you run it? In [tag:elixir-iex] everything works.

It is basically the same thing as this one, you need to wrap this into another module function and call this.
The structure module has not been compiled yet at the top level and is therefore not available.

@Aleksei Matiushkin, I tried them on iex by import_file "test.exs"

Thank you@sabiwara I can't understand why a simple calling is made so cumbersome by Elixir

.exs files are actually being compiled for performance reasons and not interpreted, unlike IEx which evaluates line by line. And the top-level is not able to access compile-time info (struct fields, ...) from modules that have not been compiled yet.

"When I run it" -> how are you running it? Try using iex text.exs instead of elixir test.exs.

@Peaceful James Both give the same error message.

If you are trying to access Person inside the same module, you have to call it using __MODULE__, eg: bob = %__MODULE__{name: "Bob"}
